# When generate Access token from Docusing using Rest Api getting errer

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

I am using following code get access token,

```
       Dim a As String = header & "." & body & "." & sign
       System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
        Dim request As WebRequest =
      WebRequest.Create("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=" & a & "")
        request.Method = "POST"

        request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{ ""Username"":""" & odjDTRep.Rows(0)("UserName").ToString() & """,  ""Password"":""" & odjDTRep.Rows(0)("Password").ToString() & """,  ""IntegratorKey"":""" & odjDTRep.Rows(0)("iss_Int_Key").ToString() & """ }")
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse() ' Here i get error
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()
```

And the error is "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different authorization technologies and types.
I'll assume that you want to use JWT because you have `grant-type:jwt` as part of the URL you are trying to make a POST call to.
To use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) you do need the X-DocuSign-Authentication header and you certainly do not need to have your password in code.
You need to [obtain consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/) once and then you need to build your Javascript Web Token and it looks like this:

```
{
  "iss": "5c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f",
  "sub": "464f7988-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-781ee556ab7a",
  "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
  "iat": 1598383123,
  "exp": 1598390123,
  "scope": "signature impersonation"
}
```

However, you need to also have an RSA Keypair and I suggest you follow [the article](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) I linked above to see how to obtain it and use it.

You can also use the [C# SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/) that has JWT support and should be able to use from a VB.NET project.
Here is VB.NET code:

```
  Sub Main()
    Dim integratorKey As String = "9e1d5046-8888-430d-9b48-xxxxxxx"
    '//Demo Environment
    Dim host As String = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
    Dim userId As String = "dcce8b59-19ec-4273-b283-xxxxxxxx" ' //geoffp.dstest@gmail.com
    Dim scopes As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    scopes.Add("signature")
    scopes.Add("impersonation")
    Dim oauthBasePath As String = "account-d.docusign.com"
    Dim RSA_Key_File As String = "C:\Users\geoff.pfander\Box Sync\geoffp\OAuth\DemoPrivate Key.txt"
    Dim privateKeyBytes() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(RSA_Key_File) ' // Create a Byte array
    Dim expiresInHours As Integer = 1
    Dim accountId As String = String.Empty
    Dim apiClient As DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient = New DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient(host)
    Dim tokenInfo As DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.OAuthToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(integratorKey, userId, oauthBasePath, privateKeyBytes, expiresInHours, scopes)
    Console.WriteLine(tokenInfo.access_token)
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for reply, actually from the article, i did step 1 and 2 and i get JWT as in variable "a" along with that url and i used header as "X-DocuSign-Authentication" . I did upto get JWT, using that JWT how to get access token ?

Comment: X-DocuSign-Authentication is the old auth, not OAuth, which article? where did you see it??